# Remove table rows based on condition in matlab

Tags: matlab

`a=[1; 2 ; 3]; b=[ 4; 5; 6 ]; T=table(a,b)`. 
I want to remove rows of table for which the value of b is less than or equal to 5 (b<=5).

Answer (score 2):

Fast, simple. elegant:

```
T(T.b <= 5,:) = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1):

```
a=[1; 2 ; 3];
b=[ 4; 5; 6 ];
T=table(a,b);

rowidx = (T.b <= 5);
T = T(~rowidx, :);
```

Which returns:

```
T =

  1×2 table

    a    b
    _    _

    3    6
```

Answer (score -1):

Another approach:

```
   a = [1; 2; 3];

   b = [4; 5; 6];

   X = [a, b];

   n = 1; m = 1;

   while (n <= size(X, 1))

       if(X(n, 2)  > 5)

           X_new(m, :) = X(n, :);

           m = m + 1;

        end

        n = n + 1;

   end
```

'X_new' will be the required matrix.